# how to modify value of an element of tensor in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am looking for keras alternative to the following numpy code

```
ratio[0][0,0,:] = ratio[0][0,0,:] - 5
```

here ratio is a keras tensor

Comment: [You may be looking for](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) `tf.where()`

Comment: i think that shall not work here, as I need to change every corner value with a separate equation, and all corner values are initially same. I mean ratio[0][0,0,:] = ratio[0][0,end,:] = ratio[0][end,0,:] = ratio[0][end, end,:]. so tf.where() will return/set all the elements, with the same values.

Comment: Tensors are immutable in TF. Check here - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [tf.scatter_nd_update()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update).

Here is an example of subtracting 5 from the tensor's last slice.

```
ratio = tf.random.uniform([2,3], minval=0.0, maxval=1.0)
indices = [[ratio.shape[0]-1]]
updates = 5.0*tf.ones([1,ratio.shape[-1]])

ratio = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_sub(ratio, indices=indices, updates=updates)

>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.43749654,  0.37062454,  0.96728885],
       [-4.8562975 , -4.260292  , -4.5968676 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

But as the commenter said, tensors are immutable, so calling the function will create *another* tensor, rather than update the tensor in-place.